# Ask about file .obj and .tds in Borland C++ compiler 5.5

Tags: c++, c, borland-c++

I used compiler gcc and g++ in Mingw. And now I using Borland C++ compiler. But I see after compile have 2 file .tds and .obj. I don't don't know what is it. Can you help me understand. Thanks very much!

Comment: `.obj` is the compiled object file. No clue what `.tds` is actually.

Comment: Why don't you have a look at it and find out? It took me a few seconds to google *"A TDS file is a Turbo Debugger Symbols File, developed by Borland."*.

Comment: I thought Borland C++ compiler is out of date by about 100 years. Is there a good reason for moving from gcc?

Answer (score 4):

.obj is the compiled object file that is used by the linker (along with the necessary library (.lib) files) to create an executable.

.tds are the Turbo Debugger symbols used for debugging. You may be able to eliminate this file in the Linker Options dialog by unchecking *Include TD32 debug info* (I don't have that version of Turbo C++ installed anywhere to check and see if it's available there) - it's not used by the IDE's debugger, IIRC; Turbo Debugger was a separate debugging tool.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you already know what an `.obj` file is.

According to [this web page](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/2377/), a `.tds` file contains debugging information (assuming BC++5.5 is pretty similar to Borland C++ Builder):

> Borland C++Builder can generate debug information as an external .TDS file.